# Security of in-transit data for Geo-Replication in Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We want to enable Geo-Replication in Azure SQL Database. However for compliance reasons, we want to be sure that replication to secondary region happens over a secure encrypted channel.

Is there any documentation available to confirm that data in-transit during geo-replication goes over a secure encrypted channel?

I have looked into Microsoft Azure Trust center and there is a brief mention about using standard protocols for in-transit data. However I could not find information related to which protocols are used and how security of in-transit data is ensured.

Comment: This is an infrastructure/compliance issue that you'll need to ask the vendor (in this case, Microsoft). Not a question that can be answered on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for this question. Yes, the geo-replication uses a secure channel. If you are using V11 servers the SSL certificates are global and regularly rotated. If you are using V12 servers the certificates are scoped to the individual logical servers. This provides secure channel isolation not only between different customers but also between different applications. Based on this post I have filed a work time to reflect this in the documentation as well.